# How to draw curved edges in Tikz in a contol flow graph of a program

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

I'm trying to draw control flow graph of a program using Tikz and want to render a output like the image below But I'm unable to draw the curved edges in the given figure.

[image]

> **The Code used for the same(but for different program)**

```
\begin{figure}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
[%
    ->,
    shorten >=2pt,
    >=stealth,
    node distance=1cm,
    noname/.style={%
      rounded corners=0.5em,
      minimum width=5em,
      minimum height=3em,
      draw,
    }
  ]
    \node[noname] (1)                                             {$Start : P$};
    \node[noname] (2) [below=of 1]                                {$c=3$};
    \node[noname] (3) [node distance=1cm and 3mm,below left=of 2] {$b = a*b$};
    \node[noname] (4) [node distance=1cm and 3mm,below right=of 2]{print $a*c$};
    \node[noname] (5) [node distance=3cm,below=of 4]              {$a=b*c$};
    \node[noname] (6) [below=of 3]                                {print $a*b$};
    \node[noname] (7) [below=of 6]                                {$Call : P$};
    \node[noname] (8) [node distance=1cm,below=of 7]              {$Return : P$};
    \node[noname] (9) [below right=of 8]                          {$Exits : P$};
    \node[noname] (10) [node distance=6cm,right =of 1]            {$Start : main$};
    \node[noname] (11) [below=of 10]                              {$a = 3$};    
    \node[noname] (12) [below=of 11]                              {$b = a*b$};    
    \node[noname] (13) [below=of 12]                              {$Call : P$};    
    \node[noname] (14) [below=of 13]                              {$Return : P$};    
    \node[noname] (15) [below=of 14]                              {$c = a*b$};    
    \node[noname] (16) [below=of 15]                              {$Exit : main$};    
    \path (1) edge                   node {} (2)
          (2) edge                   node {} (3)
          (2) edge                   node {} (4)
          (3) edge                   node {} (6)
          (4) edge                   node {} (5)
          (6) edge                   node {} (7)
          (7) edge                   node {} (8)
          (8) edge                   node {} (9)
          (5) edge [bend left = 2em]                  node {} (9)
          (10) edge                   node {} (11)
          (11) edge                   node {} (12)
          (12) edge                   node {} (13)
          (13) edge                   node {} (14)
          (14) edge                   node {} (15)
          (15) edge                   node {} (16)
          (13) edge [bend right = 1.4em]                   node {} (1)
          (9) edge  [bend left = 2.1em]                   node {} (14)
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Supergraph for given program} 
\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
```

> But it outputs image like this:

[image: This is a cfg for a different program]

How can I change the edges from node ***Call : P*** to node ***Start : P*** and node ***Exit : P*** to node ***Return : P*** to the one drawn in the desired figure above

Comment: Hi, welcome. Are you just referring to the line style (add `dotted` to edge option), or about modifying the direction the arrows enter/leave the nodes?

Comment: How to modify the direction of the arrows entering/leaving the nodes ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `in` and `out` options for the `edge`, which lets you define the angles at which the path hits the nodes. For example `out=45` means the path goes up to the right from the start node, while `in=45` means the path comes in from above right of the end node.

`dotted` will make the line dotted.

Hence, if you change the two last edges in your diagram to

```
      (13) edge [out=230,in=45,dotted]                   node {} (1)
      (9) edge  [out=-30,in=180,dotted]                   node {} (14);
```

you get:

[image]

Complete code below. (You don't need to add empty nodes for all the edges of course, so I removed the `node{}`.)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[%
    ->,
    shorten >=2pt,
    >=stealth,
    node distance=1cm,
    noname/.style={%
      rounded corners=0.5em,
      minimum width=5em,
      minimum height=3em,
      draw,
    }
  ]
    \node[noname] (1)                                             {$Start : P$};
    \node[noname] (2) [below=of 1]                                {$c=3$};
    \node[noname] (3) [node distance=1cm and 3mm,below left=of 2] {$b = a*b$};
    \node[noname] (4) [node distance=1cm and 3mm,below right=of 2]{print $a*c$};
    \node[noname] (5) [node distance=3cm,below=of 4]              {$a=b*c$};
    \node[noname] (6) [below=of 3]                                {print $a*b$};
    \node[noname] (7) [below=of 6]                                {$Call : P$};
    \node[noname] (8) [node distance=1cm,below=of 7]              {$Return : P$};
    \node[noname] (9) [below right=of 8]                          {$Exits : P$};
    \node[noname] (10) [node distance=6cm,right =of 1]            {$Start : main$};
    \node[noname] (11) [below=of 10]                              {$a = 3$};    
    \node[noname] (12) [below=of 11]                              {$b = a*b$};    
    \node[noname] (13) [below=of 12]                              {$Call : P$};    
    \node[noname] (14) [below=of 13]                              {$Return : P$};    
    \node[noname] (15) [below=of 14]                              {$c = a*b$};    
    \node[noname] (16) [below=of 15]                              {$Exit : main$};    
    \path (1) edge                   (2)
          (2) edge                   (3)
          (2) edge                   (4)
          (3) edge                   (6)
          (4) edge                   (5)
          (6) edge                   (7)
          (7) edge                   (8)
          (8) edge                   (9)
          (5) edge [bend left = 2em]                  (9)
          (10) edge                   (11)
          (11) edge                   (12)
          (12) edge                   (13)
          (13) edge                   (14)
          (14) edge                   (15)
          (15) edge                   (16)
          (13) edge [out=230,in=45,dotted]                   (1)
          (9) edge  [out=-30,in=180,dotted]                   (14);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 2):

Use `.. controls <first control point> and <second control point> .. <end point>`

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
[%
    ->,
    shorten >=2pt,
    >=stealth,
    node distance=1cm,
    noname/.style={%
      rounded corners=0.5em,
      minimum width=5em,
      minimum height=3em,
      draw,
    }
  ]
    \node[noname] (1)                                             {$Start : P$};
    \node[noname] (2) [below=of 1]                                {$c=3$};
    \node[noname] (3) [node distance=1cm and 3mm,below left=of 2] {$b = a*b$};
    \node[noname] (4) [node distance=1cm and 3mm,below right=of 2]{print $a*c$};
    \node[noname] (5) [node distance=3cm,below=of 4]              {$a=b*c$};
    \node[noname] (6) [below=of 3]                                {print $a*b$};
    \node[noname] (7) [below=of 6]                                {$Call : P$};
    \node[noname] (8) [node distance=1cm,below=of 7]              {$Return : P$};
    \node[noname] (9) [below right=of 8]                          {$Exits : P$};
    \node[noname] (10) [node distance=6cm,right =of 1]            {$Start : main$};
    \node[noname] (11) [below=of 10]                              {$a = 3$};    
    \node[noname] (12) [below=of 11]                              {$b = a*b$};    
    \node[noname] (13) [below=of 12]                              {$Call : P$};    
    \node[noname] (14) [below=of 13]                              {$Return : P$};    
    \node[noname] (15) [below=of 14]                              {$c = a*b$};    
    \node[noname] (16) [below=of 15]                              {$Exit : main$};    
    \draw (1) edge (2)
          (2) edge (3)
          (2) edge (4)
          (3) edge (6)
          (4) edge (5)
          (6) edge (7)
          (7) edge (8)
          (8) edge (9)
          (5) edge [bend left = 2em] (9)
          (10) edge (11)
          (11) edge (12)
          (12) edge (13)
          (13) edge (14)
          (14) edge (15)
          (15) edge (16);
    \draw[->] (13) .. controls +(left:4cm) and +(right:4cm) .. (1);
    \draw[->] (9)[anchor=east] .. controls +(right:3cm) and +(left:5cm) .. (14);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ..!!